# how to sync pages after logout and login on one of them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

After logout and login I try to click something on another page but see endless spinner due to userId null. How to sync Meteor.userId after changing user? ON server side:

```
Meteor.publish('myPublish', function () {
if (!this.userId) {
  return this.ready();
}
return Collection.find();});
```

On client side:

```
const handles = [
    Meteor.subscribe('settings')
  ];
  const loading = handles.some(handle => !handle.ready());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Meteor.userId` function is a reactive datasource, which allows you to autorun a Tracker and subscribe, when the userId is there.

Classic Meteor code would look like this:

```js
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  if (Meteor.userId() && Meteor.user()) {
    Meteor.subscribe('settings') // will only execute, once the user is logged in
  }
})
```

For React you use `withTracker` and should include the `Meteor.userId` to your bindings:

```js
export default withTracker(({ id }) => {
  const userId = Meteor.userId()
  const handles = userId && [
    Meteor.subscribe('todos.inList', id),
    Meteor.subscribe('otherSub'),
  ];
  const loading = !userId || handles.some(handle => !handle.ready());
  return {
    loading,
  };
})(MyComponent);
```

The call to `Meteor.userId` should activate the internal Tracker computation to re-run a cycle, once it returns a different value (a non-null value, once logged in).

You can also use `Meteor.loggingIn` as reactive data source:

```js
export default withTracker(({ id }) => {
  const loggingIn = Meteor.loggingIn()
  const handles = !loggingIn && [
    Meteor.subscribe('todos.inList', id),
    Meteor.subscribe('otherSub'),
  ];
  const loading = loggingIn || handles.some(handle => !handle.ready());
  return {
    loading,
  };
})(MyComponent);
```

References:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun

https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-userId

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn

Comment: Thank you very much It helped me. I have one more question. Have ever tried moving grom meteor to Express, MongoDB, React, Node.js? What problems werethe most difficult?

Comment: This question would attract very opinionated answers, which would not suit the format of this platform, however, you may be good advised to ask in the Meteor forums.